# Get the value of echoed string in PHP CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, echo

I need to get the value of echo-ed string in CodeIgniter or PHP.

For Example

```
class SampleClass {

 function myFunc() {
  echo "true"; 
 }

}

class TestSampleClass {

 $obj = new SampleClass();
 function test_myFunc() {
  $obj->myFunc();
  // I want to get the 'true' string to be compared..
  // how can i get the string 'true' that is echoed in myFunc()
 }

}
```

Is it possible?

Please help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why aren't you just returning a value? In CodeIgniter, you should only output/echo stuff in a view.

Answer (score 0):

While i think this question has nothing to do with CodeIgniter, you could do it by capture the buffer, and send it into some callback function to explicitely inspect the output

```
<?php
class SampleClass {

 function myFunc() 
 {
    echo 'true'; 
 }

}

class TestSampleClass {

 static function compare($buffer)
 {
    if ($buffer == 'true')
    {
       return 'Yes, it was true';
    }
    else
    {
       return 'Sorry, it was not true';
    }
 }

 function test_myFunc() 
 {
    $obj = new SampleClass();

    ob_start('TestSampleClass::compare');

    $obj->myFunc();

    ob_end_flush();
 }

}

$TSC = new TestSampleClass;

echo $TSC->test_myFunc();
?>
```

You can see the out put : http://codepad.org/LxEoh37W